# Lowest number of camera pictures needed to clear Merry Gear Solid with Big Beard ranking?

Tags: metal-gear-solid

I've just cleared [Merry Gear Solid](http://www.superfundungeonrun.com/total-klik//merrygear.html) with the Big Beard ranking - the game is only about 15 minutes long, so it wasn't too hard.

I used the digital camera 6 times and the gun none.  **I'm wondering if it's possible to complete the game with the Big Beard ranking with less than 6 camera shots** (or alternatively, 5 camera shots and 1 gun shot, using the gun on the last guard on the 8th floor)

Comment: Very cool game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it can be done with a total of **four camera uses**, or three with one gun shot, for the Big Beard ranking.

- First use in the room where you find the gun
- Second use on the 8th floor, to stun the group surrounding the hallways (before the treeline)
- Use the gun (or the camera) on the guard near the stairs after going around the treeline
- Third use on the ninth floor [as seen here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ft8Z2sfMmOM#t=95s)